# Vertically center content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, center

I am trying to center my entire content with jQuery. I've tried multiple solutions that have been posted but to no availability. My major problem is that it needs to work with IE6 thru IE8.

Here is the link: http://christopherburton.net/ie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var $inner = $('#container');

    $inner.css({ marginTop:  ($(window).height() / 2) - $inner.outerHeight() / 2 });
});
```

That would calculate and set the correct *margin-top* value once. If you want to update that when someone resizes the browser window, you need to call that code in a `resize` event on the `window` object aswell. Like

```
$(function() {
    var $inner = $('#container');
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        $inner.css({ marginTop:  ($(window).height() / 2) - $inner.outerHeight() / 2 });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmm. For some reason it's not even taking an effect.

Comment: @ChristopherBurton: works well for me if I just apply that code on your site.

Comment: It works when I insert the code in the console but not when I add it into the head section.

Comment: @ChristopherBurton: you might need to put that into a `.ready()` callback, I'll update the snippet.

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon. It only works when I resize the browser.

Comment: @ChristopherBurton: well, I can't tell what is going wrong. But if you call that `.css` line within a *document ready* handler (like in the example), it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "elem" ).css({
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%",
    marginTop: "-" + $( "elem" ).height() / 2 + "px"
});
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for that ..

Use CSS

Use this for Container class

```
#container {
position: absolute;
width: 525px;
height: 220px;
margin: 0 auto;
left: 35%;
top: 30%;
}
```

[image: Check this after adding these styles]

Comment: using css only works not that accurate. If the `#container` changes in height for instance, you need to manually adapt that `top` value all the time.

Comment: That's technically not centered and it doesn't center correctly when you resize the browser. In your screenshot you can see there is more space on the left side.